# Dropbox Java: Use Proxy with authentication

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to create my `DbxRequestConfig` Object with a `StandardHttpRequestor`, because I need it to use a Proxy.

The Proxy is a http Proxy, Port 80, and needs authentication.

```
Proxyaddress:    http://myproxy.com
Proxyport:       80
Proxyusername:   username
Proxypassword:   password
```

So I tried to use the global Java Proxy setup:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxy","proxyaddress") //... http.proxyUser, http.ProxyPassword
//and so on
```

It did not work.

After looking into the `StandardHttpRequestor` I realized I need to use this Object as well as a `Proyx` Object:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));            
StandardHttpRequestor requ = new StandardHttpRequestor(proxy);
```

Which is wrong, because it has no authentication.

For authentication, the net and google show me the following. Putting all together, my current code looks like the following:

```
String ip = "http://myproxy.com";
int port = 80;

final String authUser = "username";
final String authPassword = "password";

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
         return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
    }
});

System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));
StandardHttpRequestor requ = new StandardHttpRequestor(proxy);
return requ;
```

But this does not work as well.

What am I doing wrong?
I can't seem to get the Proxy to work.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=122258 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem was the `http://` in `String ip = "http://myproxy.com";`

My current code looks the following, and works sometimes. Sometimes not. I have no idea why. Sometimes I have to reallow the App to be connected to my DropBox Account, because the authKey doesn't come through the proxy...

Well at least I got an example working for you guys having the same trouble. Maybe the rest of the problem is on the proxy side? I'll have a further look into this. But here comes my code:

```
public HttpRequestor getProxy(){

    if("true".equals(config.getProperty("proxy","false"))){
        String ip = "proxy.myproxy.com";
        int port = 80;

        final String authUser = "username";
        final String authPassword = "password";

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
            }
        });

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress(ip,port));


        HttpRequestor req = new StandardHttpRequestor(proxy);
        return req;
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see I don't use the `StandardHttpRequestor` anymore. For the Dropbox code it is the following:

```
HttpRequestor requ = con.getProxy();
if(requ!=null)
    config = new DbxRequestConfig(APP_NAME, Locale.getDefault().toString(),requ);
else
    config = new DbxRequestConfig(APP_NAME, Locale.getDefault().toString());
```

As I already said, sometimes it works. Sometimes not. I'm going to write more info about that as soon as I know if it's because of the code or because of the proxy itself.