# Connection timeout when upload file into dropbox

Tags: java, dropbox

I got the `com.dropbox.core.NetworkIOException:` while I am trying to upload a file into dropbox account.The browser is restricted http proxy.Do I need to do any proxy configure before I can upload file into core API?

```
public class Main {
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "MY ACCESSTOCKEN";
    public static void main(String args[]) throws DbxException, IOException {
    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial", "en_US");
    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
    FullAccount account = client.users().getCurrentAccount();
    ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolder("");
    while (true) {
      for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {  }
            if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                break;
            }
            result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
        }
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt")) {
            FileMetadata metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder("/test.txt")
                .uploadAndFinish(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason is that you're behind a proxy and you can set the proxy programmatically.

For how to do it, you can refer to [Dropbox Java: Use Proxy with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523360/dropbox-java-use-proxy-with-authentication)